# Expo - React Native FileSystem error on requirement

Tags: react-native, filesystems, expo

I can't require `react-native-fs`, the app throws the exception:

```
'main' has not been registered. This can happen if: 
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project. 
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I installed it following the guide from the oficial docs.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const RNFS = require("react-native-fs");

export default function App() {
  return (

    <View>

    </View>

  );
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.3.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.11.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Obviously, if I remove the `require` line, the error disappears.

Comment: You need to import it like this ```import RNFS from "react-native-fs";```

Comment: the `require` method was from the official docs, but with this code, I still got the same, unfortunately...

Comment: Is this on Android or iOS? Please post your package.json and minimal code snippet which reproduces the issue.

Comment: sorry, just added more from my code edditing the main post.

Comment: @EnzoDtz, are you using expo?

Comment: @senthilbalaji yes, I am

Comment: Did you try using `expo-filesystem` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/? Also, if you use expo, the limitation was not to use any native module based packages, if you wanted to do so, you have to eject the src and then do it.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, at the expo docs they say that the expo has some limitations to the modules, but I just interpreted it wrong. nevermind, thank you, i'll migrate to the CLI to be more free. i'll close this